# As an independent contractor, should I always charge the client the GST/HST?

Tags: taxes, canada, hst, contractor, gst

As an independent contractor, does my hourly rate determine if I should charge GST/HST to the client? Or should I charge it always?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hourly rate is not the determinant.  You could be selling widgets, not hours.

Rather, there's a **$30,000** annual revenue threshold for GST/HST.

If your business's annual revenues fall *below* that amount, you don't need to register for GST/HST and in such case you don't charge your clients the tax.

You could still *choose* to register for GST/HST if your revenues are below the threshold, in which case you must charge your clients the tax. Some businesses voluntarily enroll for GST/HST, even when below the threshold, so they can claim input tax credits.

If your annual revenues exceed $30,000, you **must** register for GST/HST and you must charge your clients the tax.  FWIW, certain kinds of supplies are [exempt](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/gnrl/txbl/menu-eng.html), but the kind of services you'd be offering as an independent contractor in Canada aren't likely to be.

There's more to the GST/HST than this, so be sure to talk to a tax accountant.

References:

- [Canada Revenue Agency - Register for a GST/HST account](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/gnrl/stps/rgstr-eng.html)
- [Canada Revenue Agency - Charge my customers GST/HST](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/gnrl/stps/cllct-eng.html)
- [Canada Revenue Agency - Input tax credits](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/bspsbch/itc-cti/)
- [Globe & Mail - HST business questions from readers answered](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/report-on-business/small-business/sb-money/cash-flow/hst-business-questions-from-readers-answered/article4258938/?page=all)